# Unexpected behavior with .gitignore, git-status and git-check-ignore

Tags: git

I am using Git for Windows version 2.34.1 x86. I have a folder with the following contents (all path names are relative to that folder):

```
.git/
.gitignore
.vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/a
.vs/OS1/v17/Browse.VC.db
.vs/OS1/v17/Solution.VC.db
.vs/OS1/v17/ipch/AutoPCH/a
econv.txt
```

As we can see, the folder itself is under Git control. However, none of the files or folders shown above have ever been staged or committed yet, except `.gitignore`, which is already tracked.

I am unable to understand the different behavior of `git status` vs. `git check-ignore` in the following two situations:

**Situation 1**

`.gitignore` has the following content:

```
/.vs/**/
!*/
```

`git status` outputs (shortened to the interesting part)

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/
        .vs/OS1/v17/Browse.VC.db
        .vs/OS1/v17/Solution.VC.db
        .vs/OS1/v17/ipch/
        econv.txt
```

`git check-ignore -v .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` outputs

```
.gitignore:3:!*/        .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/
```

which means that `.vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` is **not ignored.** This is consistent with the above output of `git status`. So far, so good.

**Situation 2**

`.gitignore` has been changed minimally and now contains

```
/.vs/**
!*/
```

`git status` outputs (shortened to the interesting part)

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        econv.txt
```

`git check-ignore -v .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` outputs

```
.gitignore:3:!*/        .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/
```

**The question**

I understand the behavior in situation 1. `git check-ignore .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` tells me that `.vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` is not ignored, and therefore `git status` puts it into the list of untracked files (it has not been added, staged or committed yet).

But I am unable to understand the behavior in situation 2. Here, `git check-ignore .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` yields literally the same output as in situation 1, which again means that `.vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/` is **not** ignored.

However, `git status` does **not** have it in the list of untracked files any more. This seems inconsistent to me, because it should appear in the list of untracked files if it is not ignored, shouldn't it?

Could somebody please explain what is going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git never *stores* any directories (folders).  But `.gitignore` directives *can* make Git *not look inside* folders, so things get confusing here.

This rule:

```
/.vs/**/
```

applies *only to folders*, and tells Git "do not look inside these folders".

This rule:

```
!*/
```

also applies only to folders, and tells Git: "do look inside *every* folder, every time".  Since this second rule comes later, it overrides the first rule.  Since the second rule completely overrides the first rule, the first rule is irrelevant and can be removed without changing any behavior.

When you change the first rule to:

```
/.vs/**
```

it now applies to *both folders and files*.  This tells Git that for each untracked *file* in `.vs`, that file should not be added.  As all folders are by definition untracked, they're also to be "ignored" (i.e., not looked-inside).  However, the next (unchanged) rule overrides this status for folders, so folders *are* inspected, even if they are under `.vs/`.  Once inspected, all *untracked files in those folders* are ignored via the first rule.  So that first rule now matters!

So:

> `git status` does *not* have [`.vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/`] in the list of untracked files any more.

The `git status` command reports on untracked *files*, not untracked *folders* (all folders are by definition untracked and this would therefore be noisy and useless).  But `git status` will *summarize a whole bunch of files* by stripping off the file name portion and mentioning only the *containing folder*, unless you use one of the `git status` options that prevents this.

The first `git status` listing:

> ```
> Untracked files:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
>         .vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/
>         .vs/OS1/v17/Browse.VC.db
>         .vs/OS1/v17/Solution.VC.db
>         .vs/OS1/v17/ipch/
>         econv.txt
> ```

really means:

- multiple files within `.vs/OS1/FileContentIndex/`, not individually listed;
- `.vs/OS1/v17/Browse.VC.db`, individually listed
- `.vs/OS1/v17/Solution.VC.db`, individually listed
- multiple files within `.vs/OS1/v17/ipch/`, not individually listed
- `econv.txt`, individually listed

To make `git status` list the specific files *within* some folder that would otherwise be grouped together like this, use `-uall` or the longer spelling, `--untracked-files=all`.

#### Put another way ...

To put this another way:

- If a folder contains *no files at all*, it's never listed in `git status` output.  Empty folders cannot be added.  See also [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452) (there's a trick with fake or semi-fake submodules that works for this).
- If a folder contains some files, but all of those files are both *currently untracked* **and** ignored, it's not listed in `git status` output either.  That's the case for your second `.gitignore` set of rules, which carefully ignore all the files within the `.vs` folder even while carefully looking (recursively) all the way down into all sub-folders (wasted effort by definition).
- If a folder contains some tracked files but they're not modified, those files aren't listed in `git status` output.  Only if they're modified do they get listed.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>"Modified" here includes newly-added or deleted when in the "changes staged for commit" output section.  That's because this is a a `git diff --name-status` between the `HEAD` commit and the current index content.  By definition, though, the "not staged for commit" section includes only deleted or modified, not new, files.  That's because this second section's output is from a comparison between what's in Git's index and what's in your working tree, and if the file is not present in Git's index, it is by definition *untracked*, so any mention of it—if there is to be any such—belongs in the "untracked files" section.

Comment: Thank you very much for that in-depth answer, much appreciated, accepted and +1. The key point for me was: *"But git status will summarize a whole bunch of files by stripping off the file name portion and mentioning only the containing folder ..."*. Although I have read the famous Git book nearly completely, I have missed that part.